# How to copy non table data into excel using data from web funcion?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to copy some data from say wikipedia, the data apears to be formatted as a table, however when  I use the data from web function there is only one table to copy and that is the whole page, is there some way to parse the data before it comes into  the spread sheet?

I want to copy the table of career goals

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messi#Career_statistics

Comment: Have you tried to highlight and copy only the data which appears to be a table?

Comment: I can copy and paste but that defeats the purpose of the live data update. 

There does not seem to be an option to select what you want from the data import browser or I can't see it

Comment: Can you give us the web page you are working with? Otherwise, there isn't any way for us to give you a good answer (that may be why no one has responded yet).

Comment: I've updated the question